# MYSQL SQL syntax error How to resolve?

Tags: mysql

I am unable to figure out any error in this SQL statement. anyone can please help me where is error and How can I resolve this? thanks in advance and sorry for spelling or grammatical mistake.

SQL:

```
SELECT count(*) as `total` FROM `pet_info` LEFT JOIN `lostpets` ON `lostpets`.`petid` = `pet_info`.`id` WHERE `lostpets`.`reunited`='No' AND (CASE WHEN `pet_info`.`pet_aggg` = 'birth' THEN `pet_info`.`pet_birthdate` <= '2011-05-12' WHEN `pet_info`.`pet_aggg` = 'age' THEN `pet_info`.`pet_age` >= '7');
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT count(*) as `total`
FROM `pet_info` LEFT JOIN
     `lostpets`
      ON `lostpets`.`petid` = `pet_info`.`id`
WHERE `lostpets`.`reunited`='No' AND
      (CASE WHEN `pet_info`.`pet_aggg` = 'birth'
            THEN `pet_info`.`pet_birthdate` <= '2011-05-12'
            WHEN `pet_info`.`pet_aggg` = 'age'
            THEN `pet_info`.`pet_age` >= '7'
      );
```

The obvious syntax problem is the lack of `END`.  But you have other problems.  The query should probably look like this:

```
SELECT count(*) as `total`
FROM `pet_info` pi JOIN
     `lostpets` l
      ON l.`petid` = pi.`id`
WHERE l.`reunited`= 'No' AND
      ((pi.pet_aggg = 'birth' AND pi.pet_birthdate <= '2011-05-12') OR
       (pi.pet_aggg = 'age' AND pi.pet_age >= 7)
      );
```

Notes:

- Your `WHERE` clause turns the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`.
- Don't use single quotes around numeric values.
- `CASE` tends to be confusing in a `WHERE` clause.  Just use basic boolean logic.

Answer (score 1):

Just add 'end'  to the end of your select: THEN `pet_info`.`pet_age` >= '7' end);